# Connect to .Net Core service hosted on Azure AD Domain Services

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-network

I have an Azure VM connected to an Azure AD Domain Services domain. I've installed a .Net Core service  which uses HttpSys on this VM. When I'm trying to reach the url locally (from the VM), it works fine. When I try to reach the url from a VM belonging to the same subnet, it works fine too. From a VM in a Peered network too. However, when I try to reach the url from an external computer (mine), it fails.
I've open the 443 port at the VM level, at the VM NSG level and there's no firewall at the VNet level.
Is it possible to reach the service remotely? Do I need to add a User Defined Route somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can check the followings:

- network connectivity or DNS issue. You can [telnet](https://www.acronis.com/en-sg/articles/telnet/) your Azure VM public IP or the `host` in URL with the port 443 from your external computer. If fails, probably, there are network connectivity related issues between your local computer and Azure managed domain VM. Ensure you have added the authorized IP ranges to the `source` of the inbound security rules in the all NSGs that you can check from `virtual machine`---`networking`---`inbound port rules`.
  [image]
- credentials. If the Azure VM has been joined to an Azure AD Domain Services domain, make sure you have used Azure AD account with enough permission, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm#credentials-related-issues). With support for NTLM and Kerberos authentication, you can deploy applications that rely on Windows-integrated authentication. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#azure-ad-ds-features-and-benefits).
- service issue. Ensure the service could serve for external connectivity.

You also could display the detailed error for further help.

Comment: Hi Nancy, thx for the checkpoints list! I missed a small detail: dynamic IPs are... dynamic and my DNS record was obsolete after the VM was automatically shut down the day before. So, to sum up, there's no additional firewall with AAD DS regarding the VMs subnet.